# The relation between Class name and its method name at UML Class Diagram

Tags: class, uml, class-design, class-diagram, staruml

In UML Class Diagram , what is the relation between the name of class and the name of its methods? in specifically are there any consistency between their names ?

for example:

I have three classes " **Patient**" , " **Appointment**" , and "**Receptionist**"

where the "**Patient**" should do this task: " **request appointment**",
And the "**Receptionist**" do this task: "**make appointment**"

Where should I put these tasks as class methods? Should I make it all inside one class "**Appointment**" ? Or put each method in the Class that has responsibility to do it ?

[image]

Base on the previous **BPMN model** , here is a part of **My Class Digram** for the same process

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is basic design. Take *request appointment* for example:

- Who is the actor and what will he do?
- The actor is `Patient` and there should be a pool with appointments, so we model that as `Appointment`
- How is the relation between both?
- `Patient` needs to get a new `Appointment` on request.
- Place a method `makeAppointment` in `Patient`
- Where do the new appointments come from?
- There's likely a schedule that keeps all appointments and finds times for new ones.
- Create a class `Schedule` that aggregates `Appointments` and has a method `nextFreeAppointment`
- etc.

Comment: Thank you. From your answer can I conclude that :there aren't any consistency relations between "Class Name" and its " Method Name". So I place "makeAppointment" in Patient Class rather than Appointment Class